# Indicator of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $L_{A}$ the indicator of an event A

(i) Let A be an event. Show that E[$L_{A}$] = P(A)

(ii) Express $L_{A^{c}}$ (the indicator of $A^c$) in terms of $L_{A}$.

(iii) Let A, B be two events. Express $L_{A\cap B}$ in terms of $L_{A}$ and $L_{B}$

(iv) Use the previous questions to prove the identity $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

(v) Prove a formula for $P(A \cup B \cup C)$, for any three events A, B and C

I can do (i) and (iii). For (ii), is the answer 1 - $L_{A}$?

For (iv)
$A\cup B=(A\cap B^{c})\cup (A\cap B) \cup (A^{c}\cap B)$

$L_{A\cup B}=L_{(A\cap B^{c})}+L_{(A\cap B)}+L_{(A^{c}\cap B)}$

$=L_{A}\cdot L_{B^C}+L_{A} \cdot L_{B} + L_{A^c}\cdot L_{B}$

$=L_{A}\cdot (1-L_{B})+L_{A} \cdot L_{B}+(1-L_{A}) \cdot L_{B}$

$=L_{A}+L_{B}-L_{A\cap B}$

$\therefore P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Is that even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), yes:

$$\begin{align}
L_{A^c} &= \begin{cases} 1, & A^c \text{ occurs} \\ 0, & A^c \text{ does not occur} \end{cases} \\
&= 1 - \begin{cases} 0, & A^c \text{ occurs} \\ 1, & A^c \text{ does not occur} \end{cases} \\
&= 1 - \begin{cases} 0, & A \text{ does not occur} \\ 1, & A \text{ occurs} \end{cases} \\
&= 1 - L_A,
\end{align}$$
where we use the property that $(A^c)^c = A$, and the property that if $A$ occurs, then $A^c$ does not occur (and vice versa); i.e., $A$ and $A^c$ are mutually exclusive and partition the space of elementary outcomes.

For (iv), I'm not sure how you can start with that assertion.  You are correct that $$A \cup B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B),$$ but this does not immediately imply the subsequent relationship among the indicator functions, because you have not established from the previous parts of the question that the indicator of an event $C$ is equal the sum of the indicators of events that partition $C$.

Instead, I would reason as follows:  Observe that $$A \cup B = (A^c \cap B^c)^c,$$ so $$L_{A \cup B} = L_{(A^c \cap B^c)^c} = 1 - L_{A^c \cap B^c}$$ from part (ii).  Then applying (iii) again (with the complements of $A$ and $B$) we get
$$L_{A \cup B} = 1 - L_{A^c} L_{B^c}.$$
Now apply (ii) again:
$$L_{A \cup B} = 1 - (1-L_A)(1-L_B) = 1 - 1 + L_A + L_B - L_A L_B = L_A + L_B - L_{A \cap B},$$
where in the last step we again applied (iii).  Take the expected value, and  apply the linearity of expectation:
$$\mathbb E[L_{A \cup B}] = \mathbb E[L_A + L_B - L_{A \cap B}] = \mathbb E[L_A] + \mathbb E[L_B] - \mathbb E[L_{A \cap B}],$$
and now apply (i).

I will leave part (v) as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

> For (ii), is the answer $1 - L_A$?

Yes, $L_{A^\complement} = \begin{cases}0& A\\1& A^{\complement}\end{cases}=1-L_A$.

and likewise you may show $L_{A\cup C}=L_A+L_C$ for all *disjoint* events $A, C$.

---

And $L_{A\cup B} = L_A+L_B-L_{A\cap B}$ for *all* events, by the reasons you used below.

> For (iv) $A∪B=(A∩B^\complement)∪(A∩B)∪(A^\complement ∩B)$

Indeed.  Expressing the union as a *union of disjoint events*, leads to:  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B) &=\mathsf E(L_{A\cup B})\\&=\mathsf E(L_{(A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B)})\\&=\mathsf E(L_A(1-L_B)+L_AL_B+(1-L_A)L_B)\\&=\mathsf E(L_A+L_B-L_{A\cap B})\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\end{align}$$